# Last video player location?

Tags: resident-evil-7

I've gone post point-of-no-return, and finished part of game

> on ship as Mia

Now, I have two tapes, where I didn't got achievements yet (speedrun for "Happy Birthday", and don't get caught on "Mia"). I was hoping to finish this before last episode of game, somewhere

> before or in salt mine,

But I can't find any video player. So, my question is - where is actually last video player? Is it one in

> Testing area?

Or can I use video player while

> revisiting guest house?

**Update:**
Ok, last option is invalid - there is no video player there.

Comment: Apparently you can use the video player on the ship (the same one that you *have* to use as part of the game). I haven't tried this myself though so I can't confirm for sure. Other than that, it would be the one you have already mentioned

Comment: @musefan the issue is, that this video player can be accessed only as Mia, who doesn't have access to Ethan items (and, obviously, "Mia" and "Happy Birthday" tapes). So it is not an option.

Comment: Well I guess you have your answer then

Answer (score 1):

It seems that last video player is actually in

> monitoring room in the end of testing area.